# Does u-boot itself get initialized based on the contents of a device tree?

Tags: arm, embedded, u-boot, device-tree

All sources that I have found so far have mentioned that device tree blobs are used as part of Linux initialization after u-boot is already up and running. I am trying to bring up u-boot itself on my ARM board and I see many OF errors in parsing the dtb even before I get to the u-boot console. Does u-boot use the device tree directly? Would you please point to any relevant documentation on this process? Thanks!

Comment: *"I see many OF errors in parsing the dtb"* --  Add the complete console output so that we can see what you're referring to.  Since you didn't bother to indicate what version of U-Boot that you're using, be sure to include that portion of the log.

Comment: I would assume not, your errors are probably uboot trying to launch linux or prepare to.  but as mentioned/implied everyone and their brother uses uboot, various versions and everyone has to customize to some extent to their platform, so while unlikely it is possible that someone is doing it.  I would assume if you are getting errors then you are already running uboot, which means you dont have the chicken and egg problem of it needing it to run to see that the thing it needed was bad.

Comment: https://github.com/lentinj/u-boot/blob/master/doc/README.fdt-control It depends on your configuration and version of u-boot.  Certainly more recent ARM  Linux use DT (~2010+ or V2.6.30?).  U-boot itself can also use device tree to configure a board.  There is  a configure *CONFIG_OF_CONTROL* item of modern u-boots.